# Why is R removing factors from factor variables when I run a quantile regression?

Tags: r, categorical-data, quantile, quantreg

I'm currently running a quantile regression model in R using Roger Koenker's `quantreg` package.  I have an ordered categorical variable with five levels and three unordered categorical variables (day of the week, season, and whether or not it's nighttime) with seven, four, and two categories, respectively.  All are originally stored in the data frame as strings except the ordered categorical variable, which is five levels from 1 to 5.  Here's how I code the previously-mentioned variables as factors.  Note that my variable is called `df_prime` because it's the original data frame with some pruned rows:

```
df_prime$acuity_id <- ordered(df_prime$acuity_id, c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
df_prime$day_of_week <- as.factor(df_prime$day_of_week)
df_prime$season <- as.factor(df_prime$season)
df_prime$is_night <- as.factor(df_prime$is_night)
```

When I run the regression, it completely cuts Friday from the summary and one of the levels of my acuity_id, which is my ordered variable.  Is that possibly related to how R creates dummy variables?  I'm noticing that seasonWinter has a p-value of 1 for whatever reason.

My output is as follows, although with different spacing because my workplace has R on a VM and I can't copy and paste:

```
                 Value           Std. Error     t value          Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)          173.20000       5.84510        29.63167         0.00000
day_of_weekMonday     19.33333       3.60107         5.36878         0.00000
day_of_weekSaturday  -49.66667       3.41145       -14.55883         0.00000
day_of_weekSunday    -42.00000       3.35297       -12.52620         0.00000
day_of_weekThursday    5.33333       3.51831         1.51588         0.12957
day_of_weekTuesday     3.00000       3.51917         0.85247         0.39396
day_of_weekWednesday   1.66667       3.75717         0.44360         0.65734
is_night1            -53.00000       2.04268       -25.94626         0.00000
seasonAutumn           8.00000       4.37771         1.82744         0.06765
seasonSpring          -0.66667       4.46209        -0.14941         0.88123
seasonSummer          12.66667       4.40002         2.87877         0.00400
seasonWinter           0.00000       4.36418         0.00000         1.00000
acuity_id.L           37.94733      11.20886         3.38548         0.00071
acuity_id.Q         -108.68624       9.48982       -11.45293         0.00000
acuity_id.C          -36.36619       5.93905        -6.12324         0.00000
acuity_id^4           25.61773       2.77411         9.23459         0.00000
```

Comment: With treatment contrasts one factor level (against which other levels are compared) is represented by the intercept.

Comment: Thanks!  So the "missing" information for Friday and the missing acuity level is incorporated into the intercept?  Also, what do .L, .Q, and .C represent for the acuity levels?  I assume ^4 means to the fourth power.

Comment: You need to study what treatment contrasts and polynomial contrasts are.

Comment: @Roland Thanks! I just looked up the Wikipedia page on contrasts and they do use means. Will that be a problem for highly skewed data like the kind I'm working with (it's immune to taking logs.)? That's why I used quantile regression to begin with.  And is there a way to do contrasts based on quantiles?